# Nextjs | Why getInitialProps is not generating one page per result (SEO)?

Tags: javascript, seo, next.js

I've built a project using Next.js. There are 2 pages on this website but when I run a sitemap generator it only crawls one, the index one. I think that if these crawlers don't detect other pages, the search engines wouldn't either.

**Next.js** version: 10.0.2

**React** version: 17.0.1

Here is the pages directory's structure:

```
pages/
├── index.js
├── courses
│   ├── [course].js
```

As you can see, I'm generating every course dynamically using `getInitialPros`.

```
Curso.getInitialProps = async (ctx) =>{
  const {query} = ctx;
  const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/data.json');
  const coursesList = await response.json();
  let courseIndex = coursesList.map(function (e) {return e.path;}).indexOf(query.course);
  let courseObj = coursesList[courseIndex];
  return({courseObj: courseObj})
}
```

And here is the component that renders the course that match the URL:

```
const Curso = ({courseObj })=> {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
     <h2> {courseObj.title} </h2>
...
}
```

The website works fine, I can access every course using the list of links (as I'm working with Next.js, I'm using `<Link />` from `'next/link'` to navigate in the website)  on the index page or directly from the navigation bar. I've tried to solve this using [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs) but I got the same result.

***UPDATE***

When I run build in the directory this is what I get
[image]

After the build has been created, the page folder contains the following files:

```
pages/
├── index.js
├── courses
│   ├── [course].js
```

Comment: It would help if you could improve your question by actually mentioning a few more details. What version of NextJS are you using? What static site generator are you using? If you are using NextJs > 9.3 I would advise you to use `getStaticProps` and then check the build folder to see if your pages have been rendered. If they are then my guess is that your sitemap generator might be at fault.

Comment: @ovidb I’ve added the suggested information but I think this is not a problem with the web crawler but with my code. The pages should be created when, as you said, the run build command is executed